# How to select date on click from Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have Bootstrap Datepicker and I want to set default date when click on `Set Date` button.

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-append date datepicker no-padding" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input class="input-medium" id="date" size="16" type="text"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
<a href="#" id="set_date">Set Date</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    
    $("#set_date").click(function(){
      date ="07/01/2015";
      $("#date").val(date); 
    });
});
```

I set date using `jQuery` but it do not show as selected date. My question is How to set `date` on click and show as selected date.

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuG6C/601/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read this http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

here after update your example
 http://jsfiddle.net/tuG6C/614/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();

    $("#set_date").click(function(){
      date ="07-01-2015";
      //$("#date").val(date); 
      $( '.datepicker' ).datepicker( "setDate", date );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your javascript with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();

    $("#set_date").click(function(){
      date ="07/01/2015";

        var d = new Date();
        var curr_day = d.getDate();
        var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
        var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

        var today = curr_month + "/" + curr_day + "/" + curr_year;
        $("#date").val(today); 


    });
});
```

check js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/swapnilmotewar/tuG6C/609/

Comment: I want to `set` and `show` as selected date when click on `set date` link

Comment: What do you want?? please explain it?

Comment: I want to set `date = 07/01/2015` and display in datepicker selected date like `blue` color for selected date in datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace:

```
$("#date").val(date);
```

With:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker("update", date);
```